# how to report some illegal website to FBI or crime department

Tags: internet, legal

I asked this question on stackoverflow and they suggested this

I dont know whether i can ask this question here or not

I am finding many web forums supportingstealing of personal info like creditcards and they selling at 2$ each and thye making gift vouchers of main auction websites and selling them 500$ at 10$ (these guys looping people hardwork )

where can i report these type of sites if i found in internet ?

can anyone please tell me exactly where can i report

regards

steve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ic3.gov/default.aspx) is a site setup specifically for reporting internet fraud. The thing is while a country's various police departments have the knowledge and capability to route complaints to the the country / department with jurisdiction, at least some time and effort must be spent on any investigation. The rub then is do they think the fraud / crime being committed is costing enough people enough money to spend any of their resources pursuing it. They are likely to agree that there is a crime being committed, but that it simply does not rise to a level that warrants investigation.

Comment: IC3's mission is to serve as a vehicle to receive, develop, and refer criminal complaints regarding the rapidly expanding arena of cyber crime. This seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for. Good link Beaner.

Comment: They however, look to be an american organization. Which probably doesn't have much authority in the rest of the world.

Comment: From the website: "For law enforcement and regulatory agencies at the federal, state, local and international level, IC3 provides a central referral mechanism for complaints involving Internet related crimes" Notice that they mention internation level.

Comment: @Indigas: The average person has very little hope of even determining the correct jurisdiction. You report it, law enforcement investigates it, and prosecutors determine jurisdiction. Law enforcement is able to cooperate across political boundaries to attack multi-jurisdictional crime organizations. The site I linked is setup specifically to report Internet crime, regardless of the country of origin. Please see their FAQ: http://www.ic3.gov/faq/default.aspx

Comment: I ment that in the sense that although some organizations (like the mentioned) want to be international, laws are still local. And many (and I do mean many!) countries ahve laws totally uncompatible with britain&americas ... so, no go. Example: look what it took just to take down pirate bay ... and sweden has modern laws. And it still required political pressure to take down one page.

Comment: @Indigas: You are correct, successful prosecution is very difficult, but the question was how to report it. Reporting is about all the average person can do. Different countries, different laws, different political priorities. Pretty much explains why internet crime is growing.

Answer (score 4):

It's very difficult. The internet is a world-wide thing, so reporting, say, The Pirate Bay to the FBI is useless, as it's not under their juristiction. The first step, then, would be to find out where the *server* is located*, and after making sure such actions are illegal in that country, reporting it to the relevent body.

*I've always used the first tool to turn up in a google search, like [this](http://www.81solutions.com/server-location.html).

Comment: i already found server is located in UK

Comment: Well that's illegal over here, but I'm not sure who you'd have to contact.

Answer (score 2):

> i already found server is located in
>   UK

if related to the UK, try the **[PCeU - Police Central e-crime Unit](http://www.met.police.uk/pceu/)**

Comment: It uses $ and talks about the FBI. I think it's safe to assume he's American.

Comment: Check the comments on my answer - the server is located in the UK, and that's what's important, regardless of what nationality the members are.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to get through to anyone in law enforcement who has the authority or will to tackle stuff like this. Even in easy, single-country cases (which are few), it's very rare to get any action taken. It's extremely frustrating.

You might have better luck complaining to the ISP hosting the material. But be sure to complain at the right level. Many apparent ISPs are no more than front operations for criminal activity, and it's common for Russian-AWM-complex fronts to operate from a mailbox in London. You say the server is hosted in the UK; check the bona fides of each organisation upwards to find one that's really a reputable hosting operation to complain to.

(Even if you succeed, you'll just be pushing them on to the next hosting location of course.)